# Node.js how to pass function argument by reference in practice

Tags: javascript, node.js, pass-by-reference

I have found the following suggestions on how to pass parameter by reference using built-in JavaScript functionality: 
[[Javascript] Pass By Value And Pass By Reference In JavaScript](https://medium.com/nodesimplified/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c) 
[TypeScript pass by ref parameter [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132127/typescript-pass-by-ref-parameter)

However, none of them work in practice. Consider the following code example:

```
let data = {
    prop1: '[1,2,3]',
    prop2: '{"abc":"def"}'
}

function parseString(ref prop) {
    if(typeof prop === 'string') {
        prop = JSON.parse(prop);
    }
}

parseString(data.prop1);
parseString(data.prop2);
```

Using the boxing approach `{item: data.prop1}` does not work because the box will contain a copy and not a reference to the original `data.prop1` property.

How to properly implement the above example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to implement `parseString` function is by specifying the parent object and a string to indicate the referenced property. Here is the code that implements the example:

```
function parseString(data, propName) {
    if (!Object.keys(data).includes(propName)) {
        throw new Error(`Object does not contain key ${propName}.`);
    }

    if(typeof prop === 'string') {
        data[propName] = JSON.parse(data[propName]);
    }
}

parseString(data, 'prop1');
parseString(data, 'prop2');
```